# Woocommerce hover effect: how to change price to add to cart button

Tags: html, woocommerce, hover, cart, price

If you go with your mouse over the price then it will change too add to cart button, like a hover. Which html/css codes I have to do this?

Tried: 
- disable the add to cart button and use the hover method but does not works..
- Using paddings margins in css, but If I make the page bigger the button will go to the right and you will see the price.

I will like do this to have more clearly pages.

I would like to use it on homepage/productpage.

Comment: Try to provide some code in order to make it clearer where your problem is

Comment: Iv tried. but 2 in 1 solution is perfect. If you see to much add to cart button its not clear. So if you use both of them, first price and then with your mouse over the price you will see the add to cart button. Its hard to find the solution anyway